# Can't bind to 'userID' since it isn't a known property of 'view-user'

Tags: angular

I have the following template expression:

which refers to ViewUserComponent which contains:

```
@Input() userID;
```

Why I get the following error?

```
Can't bind to 'userID' since it isn't a known property of 'view-user'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ViewUserComponent wasn't in the app.module.ts `declrations[]` array

Answer (score 0):

1) **ngIf="doSelect"** can create problem so be sure about it that it works as expected.

2) **[userID]="selectedUser?.id"** as shown, you can try `?.` operator (I assume SelectedUser object comes from server).

Comment: Changed to `<view-user *ngIf="selectedUser" [userID]="selectedUser?.id"></view-user>` and still get the same error